# Filter records based on the currently logged in user

Tags: oracle, where-clause, filtering, oracle-apex

I created a task assignment app in Oracle Apex with several interactive grid pages based on the table I created. The table is called `DEMANDE_INTERVENTION` and has a column (among others) called `DEMANDEUR`. In one page, I wanted to only display the records that have a value of `DEMANDEUR` that is equal to the name of the logged user. I tried adding the condition `DEMANDEUR=:APP_USER` in the `WHERE` clause but it didn't seem to work. I also tried using the conditions:

`DEMANDEUR = V('APP_USER')`

`DEMANDEUR =SYS_CONTEXT('APEX$SESSION', 'APP_USER')`

`DEMANDEUR =SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','AUTHENTICATED_IDENTITY')`

`DEMANDEUR =SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','CURRENT_SCHEMA')`

`DEMANDEUR =SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','CURRENT_USER')`

[image]

[image]

I also tried to check what's inside `:APP_USER` by using the query:

```
  select DEMANDEUR,
       INTERVENTION,
       ETAT_IMPORTANCE,
       "VALIDÉE_PAR",
       ETAT_INTERVENTION,
       LIEU,
       "DATE_DE_CRÉATION",
       OBSERVATION,
       :APP_USER
  from DEMANDE_INTERVENTION
```

but only the first column was shown:

[image]

What can I do to resolve this?

Comment: Should it not be ```:APP_USER``` ?

Comment: I also tried it but it didn't work

Comment: Why don't you put a text item on the page with the value :APP_USER and verify it is set to what you think it is? It can depend on what the authentication method is.

Comment: From my point of view, it is exactly what @Shivam said - invalid usage of application item's name. It **is** `:APP_USER` and condition should have been `where requester = :APP_USER` (pay attention to colon position!).

Answer (score 3):

I don't use APEX, but if it logs you in as yourself (private account) rather than a common app account, and this is the user you are referring to, then regardless of what your client application environment is, within the database itself in either SQL or PL/SQL you can always use the variable `USER` to get the identity of the currently logged-in user. So:

```
SELECT ..
 WHERE requester = USER
```

Should work for you. Also available are several "USERENV" options:

```
SELECT ..
 WHERE requester = SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','AUTHENTICATED_IDENTITY') -- account used to connect to the database (can be different if proxy is used)

SELECT ..
 WHERE requester = SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','CURRENT_SCHEMA') -- default schema if objects are not fully qualified. Can be changed by ALTER SESSION SET CURRENT_SCHEMA

SELECT ..
 WHERE requester = SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','CURRENT_USER') -- user whose privs are active. In stored procs can be the procedure owner (not the session executing it) if AUTHID is at its default of DEFINER.
```

Answer (score 2):

In any apex session, the value of the current user is stored in a bind variable `APP_USER`. Within sql/plsql this variable can be accessed as a bind variable using the syntax `:APP_USER`. Note there is no space between the ":" and "APP_USER" as in your example.

If you want to access the variable in an object (view/package/trigger/...) then a bind variable is not an option. In that cause the sys_context variable `SYS_CONTEXT('APEX$SESSION', 'APP_USER')` or the older "V" function (`V('APP_USER')`)

All documented [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/apex/22.1/htmdb/using-substitution-strings.html#GUID-3AFC7346-902C-4DCA-8D28-960BD8FC6628)

Now to answer your question *What can I do to resolve this ?*. Well... debug. Create a report with source

```
  SELECT requester, :APP_USER from "TaskAssignment"
```

And check the output. Maybe the case doesn't match and you need to do UPPER/LOWER on a side of the equation to solve that ? That is up to you. It is your data, your database and up to you to fix ;)

--Update--

Looking at the report output it looks like the column "demandeur" has mixed case data. I'm assuming that is the issue. Change the where clause to :

```
UPPER(demandeur) = UPPER(:APP_USER)
```

Comment: I tried putting all of these condition in the WHERE clause at the source in the sidebar of the Page Designer but none of them worked. I also tried to query the  `:APP_USER` as recommended in the last query but only the the requester column was displayed in the interactive report, not even with another column with `NULL` values.

Comment: My example on how to debug has no where clause. Please update your question with the exact source of that debug report and the output, as screenshots pls.

Comment: I understand. I edited the post accordingly.

Comment: The column you added is hidden by default. Show it in actions > columns. Or create a new report with the query I showed you. At this point you're debugging. It's OK to add new regions or pages to debug. They can easily be removed